# Scrapy not filling object on request

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Here is my code

spider.py

```
def parse(self,response):
    item=someItem()
    cuv=Vitae()
    item['cuv']=cuv
    request=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.cvsearch)
    request.meta['item'] = item
    yield request

def cvsearch(self, response):
    item=response.meta['item']
    cv=item['cuv']
    cv['link']=response.url
    return item
```

items.py

```
class someItem(Item):
   cuv=Field()

class Vitae(Item):
   link=Field()
```

No errors are displayed!

It adds the object "cuv" to "item" but attributes to "cuv" are never added, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a very good explainer but I'll try to explain what's wrong best I can

Scrapy is asynchronous meaning there is no order which requests are executed. Let's take a look at this piece of code

```
def parse(self,response):
   item=someItem()
   cuv={}
   item['cuv']=cuv
   request=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.cvsearch)
   request.meta['item'] = item
   yield request
   logging.error(item['cuv']) #this will return null [1]

def cvsearch(self, response):
   item=response.meta['item']
   cv=item['cuv']
   cv['link']=response.url
   return item
```

[1]-this is because this line will execute before cvsearch is done which you can't control. To solve this you have to do a cascade for multiple requests

```
def parse(self,response):
   item=someItem()
   request=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.cvsearch)
   request.meta['item'] = item
   yield request

def cvsearch(self, response):
   item=response.meta['item']
   request=scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.another)
   yield request

def another (self, response)
   item=response.meta['item']
   yield item
```

To fully grasp this concept I advise to take a look at multithreading. Please add anything that I missed!

Answer (score 1):

Why you use scrapy.Item inside another one?
Try using a simple python dict inside your `item['cuv']`. And try to move `request.meta` to `scrapy.Request` constructor argument.
And you should use `yield` instead of `return`

```
def parse(self,response):
    item=someItem()
    request=scrapy.Request(url, meta={'item': item} callback=self.cvsearch)
    yield request

def cvsearch(self, response):
    item=response.meta['item']
    item['cuv'] = {'link':response.url}
    yield item
```

Comment: but I want to keep working on the item in the parse method, is it ok to do it?

Anyway, still not working, it returns empty

Comment: Still not working, I did the dict just as you said and when I do `logging.error(item)` in the cvsearch method it shows alright but when I do the same in the parse method after `yield request` it's not there anymore

Comment: Have you tried to use `meta={'item':item}` on `scrapy.Request` constructor?

Comment: yes, `request=scrapy.Request(response.url,meta={'item':item}, callback=self.cvsearch)`, I think the problem is that `logging.error(item)` is executed before the cvsearch method has finished parsing but if that is the case I have no clue how to confirm or how to fix!

Comment: What version of scrapy you are using?

Comment: 1.0.5, I know what the problem is already, I'll make an answer once I finish the code and explain what's wrong, thanks for all your input